# How to detect ngModel dirty?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I have a screen where the `input` fields gets populated dynamically based on the API response. Each input field has a set of buttons associated with it. I want to show the buttons only when the field is dirty.

Below is a screenshot of the form -

[image: form]

I'm using simple `ngModel` to view & change the values. As the fieds doesn't have any complex validations I'm not looking to use reactive form approach. When a user types on a field it's corresponding button set should appear. On click of either the button the field should again get marked as pristine.

Below is my code of populating the template -

```html
<h5 class="mb-4">Report Configuration</h5>
<div class="form-group row" *ngFor="let config of reportConfig">
  <label class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-form-label">{{config.title}} <span
      class="text-danger">*</span></label>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
    <input type="text" [class.is-invalid]="false" [id]="config.propertyKey" [(ngModel)]="config.propertyValue" class="form-control" />
    <!-- On typing the field should be marked dirty & buttons should appear -->
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2 pl-0">
    <mat-icon class="mr-2" (click)="should mark the field pristine">check_small</mat-icon>
    <mat-icon color="warn" (click)="should mark the field pristine">close_small</mat-icon>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is this can be achieved using `ngModel` or I need to use `FormArray` only to acheive this?

Answer (score 2):

A ngModel Inherited from AbstractControlDirective, so you can access to his properties valid, touched or dirty. To do it use a template reference variable (the "#nameID" in the code below)

```
<div *ngFor="let config of reportConfig">
    <input name="name" #nameID="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="config .name"/> 
    <button *ngIf="nameID.dirty">undo</button>

    <pre>
    {{nameID.control.dirty}} or {{nameID.dirty}}
    {{nameID.control.touched}} or {{nameID.touched}}
    {{nameID.control.valid}} or {{nameID.valid}}
    </pre>
</div>
```

Rememeber that a template reference variable has his own "scope" under a ngFor, so you have no problem to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Just try adding this in your ngModel in html

```
(change)="checkDirty(value)"
```

and this code in your ts file

```
checkDirty(value) {
 if (value.dirty) {
  //your code on here
 }
}
```

As for explanation, the ngModel supports [dirty](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControlDirective#dirty) property in it, and in each value change it will check if the input is dirty or not

Comment: It's not necessary, ngModel inherited from AbstractControlDirective

Answer (score 0):

You can set a template reference variable with the # mark:

```
<input #variable="ngModel" type="text" [class.is-invalid]="false" [id]="config.propertyKey" [(ngModel)]="config.propertyValue" class="form-control" />
```

after that, you can change the pristine property with markAsPristine() function call:

```
<mat-icon class="mr-2" (click)="variable.control.markAsPristine()">check_small</mat-icon>
```

Check this example in the official documentation: https://angular.io/guide/forms#show-and-hide-validation-error-messages

Note: Reactive forms are not only for form validation, they give you access to the form values, while the template-driven form does not.